# qml qt 5.12 using modules controls1 and controls2 in one program

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, qtquickcontrols

I can't use QtQuick.Controls 1.2 and QtQuick.Controls 2.12 in one program. Although in Qt 5.10 this worked. Now I get this message when I load main.qml:
*"qrc:/MyButton.qml 2 module QtQuick.Controls 2.12 is not installed"*

Qt 5.12. Build on macOS for ios or ios emulator.

**pro file**

```
QT += quick quickcontrols2
CONFIG += c++11
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
RESOURCES += qml.qrc
QML_IMPORT_PATH =
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
Window {
    visible: true
    Button {
        id: button1
        text: "Controls 1 button"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MyButton {
        text: "Controls 2 button"
        anchors {
            top: button1.bottom
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
    }
}
```

**MyButton.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
Button {
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

**qml.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>MyButton.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Perhaps there are some restrictions or rules that need to be followed to make it work? If use only Constools 1.2 or only Constols 2.12, then main.qml loaded successfully.

p.s. Build on windows for windows and build on windows for android works fine. The problem is only with build on mac os for ios/ios emulator.

Comment: what is your Qt version?

Comment: Qt 5.12. Build on macOS for ios or ios emulator.

Comment: Try to change `QtQuick.Controls 2.12` to `...Controls 2.2` or `2.3`, `2.4`...

Comment: trying to use versions 2.1 and 2.2 does not fix the bug. checking the rest

Comment: yes, does not fix but we need to know the version you have installed

Comment: look at this https://forum.qt.io/topic/50948/how-to-find-in-documenation-the-qtquick-versions-for-a-qt-version

Comment: Checked all versions from 2.1 to 2.12 - not fix bug (provided that the main.qml remains the use of Qt Quick.Controls 1.2)

Comment: If set version 2.12 in main.qml and in MyButton.qml window is loaded. This indicates that the module Controls 2.12 is installed and it can work.

Comment: To solve the problem, the project is refactored to use only Controls 2.